# Get all the jira information by hitting api using ruby

Tags: ruby, jira-rest-api

I need to get all the information from a particular **Jira** using rest api in **ruby**,

I have tried using my credentials and my companies Jira URL, it's working fine but I want to do this without my credentials, I don't have much idea about it, using some access token some said it can be done, but I don't know how!

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'pp'
require 'jira-ruby'

options = {
 username: '',
 password: '', 
 site: '',
 context_path: '',
 auth_type: :basic,
 use_ssl: true
}

client = JIRA::Client.new(options)
projects = client.Project.all

# Show all projects
# issues = client.Project.find('ion_authn_engine').issues

projects.each do |project|
 puts "name: #{project.name}"
end
```

I'm getting all the jira's but I have to use my credentials here, can it be done in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify is you were using Jira Cloud or Jira on-prem.

If you are using the Cloud version, you can use [API tokens](https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/api-tokens-938839638.html)

If you are using the [on-prem solution](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/security-overview/), you can use OAuth, or cookies besides basic auth.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I will try this first.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to connect to a Jira instance (3 if you count your personal login/password).

1. Using an account-based API key
2. Using a [server-generic oauth application key](https://confluence.atlassian.com/applinks/oauth-troubleshooting-guide-790632058.html#OAuthtroubleshootingguide-OAuthunknownkey)

Think of the long-term use case before deciding which one.

### Account based API

The account based API key is connected with your account (whichever is used to make it).  This means it will have your account's permissions, including however ever they will change.  That could lead to unexpected behavior from the integrated apps, if your perms change without planning / coordination.

Also, this can be ideal, as the accounts API key is then a 'flexible permissions window' into the Jira server.  It's a good solution if you may want later to change what can go out over the query.  Maybe you want to make a few such accounts with different perms, so that the app can dynamically query data without seeing too much, ever.

Also, you can create these account-based API keys without involving your server's admin. They're just another thing a user can do.

#### Where to find it

[image: URL where to find personal API keys]

#### A Revokable Password

[image: revokable password]

### Server generic Oauth

This kind of connection will always have unfettered access to the Jira instance's data.  This is a master key, and it's permissions can never be reduced.

Oauth keys need to be setup by a Jira `site admin`, since they bypass all other permissions levels.  They are suitable for do BI data links, which it sounds like that's what you're doing here.  They're more effort to setup, but more predictable long-term.  There's no mistake that the can be delete or changed by any of the admin actions that can impact user accounts.